# Not repeating the same number twice in a row when calling random number from array

Tags: ios, swift, random, sprite-kit

I have an array that contains 8 `CGPoints`:

```
let easyArray = [CGPointMake(0,0), CGPointMake(126.6,0), CGPointMake(253.4,0), CGPointMake(0,197.5), CGPointMake(126.7,197.5), CGPointMake(253.4,197.5), CGPointMake(0,395), CGPointMake(126.7,395), CGPointMake(253.4,395)]
```

I then have an object that moves to one of the points using a random function:

```
//Moving the object
let easyPos = randomInt(0,8)
let moveSelector = SKAction.moveTo(easyArray5s[easyPos], duration: 0)
easySelector5s.runAction(moveSelector)

//Random Function
func randomInt(min: Int, max:Int) -> Int {
return min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1)))
}
```

The problem I am having is that sometimes the object will move to one location then stay in that same location again. In other words the same location will get used twice one after another. How can I make it so that this doesn't happen. I am using swift.

Answer (score 1):

Move chosen point to the end of the array (and last point move to the chosen place - i.e. switch them). And don't include last point in the next random choice (just remove +1 from arc4random_uniform).

Comment: I removed the 1 but i am still having the same issue. Could you please provide some further assistance.
return min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min)))

Comment: It's not an exact code, but I hope you will see the idea, do it on every move  `temp = arr[easyPos]; arr[easyPos] = arr[arr.length - 1]; arr[arr.length - 1] = temp; ` , as I see you missed **Move chosen point to the end of the array (and last point move to the chosen place - i.e. switch them)** part

Comment: New idea (old one is still valid), without switch: `newPos = (oldPos + rand(0, length-1)) % length;`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are want to do -

```
return min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min))) + 1
```

Comment: I removed the 1 but i am still having the same issue. Could you please provide some further assistance. return min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min)))